# How to avoid nested weights?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a xml layout to enter a pincode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pinDisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:background="@null" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backspace"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Keypad section -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:attr/text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="#B8B8B8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout is fine, but I get a lot of Lint warnings about nested weights.

> Nested weights are bad for performance

I don't really notice the layout loading slow or anything. What can I do to avoid nested weights? Or should I just leave it like it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use RelativeLayout to avoid the nested weights.

Nested weights are bad for performance because the number of measurements increase exponentially with each one nested.

Answer (score 11):

In general, you should try to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) instead of nesting many LinearLayouts.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html):

> Note: Although you can nest one or more layouts within another layout
>   to acheive your UI design, you should strive to keep your layout
>   hierarchy as shallow as possible. Your layout draws faster if it has
>   fewer nested layouts (a wide view hierarchy is better than a deep view
>   hierarchy).

But when you need weights, like now, a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) wouldn't help you much; instead, I suggest using a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) for your keypad, to reduce the number of nested layouts.